# Quais são exemplos reais e práticos no uso de Stored Procedures?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, stored-procedures

Ao participar de uma entrevista para o cargo de desenvolvedor, deparo com uma pergunta relacionada a ***Stored Procedure*** (*SP*) e a princípio tenho conhecimento teórico sobre assunto, mas nunca me deparei com um exemplo prático no uso da (*SP*) e fui incapaz de dar um bom exemplo nessa situação por falta de vivência sobre o assunto.

Dito que conceitualmente a *SP* serve por exemplo, para:

> 1. reduzir o tráfego de rede
> 2. melhorar a performance de banco de dados
> 3. criar tarefas agendadas
> 4. diminuir riscos
> 5. criar rotinas de processamentos

(fonte: [devMedia](https://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-aos-stored-procedures-no-sql-server/7904))

Alguém com mais experiência, poderia compartilhar com um exemplo real, prático e que facilmente pode ser usado em uma resposta concisa e objetiva sobre o assunto?

Comment: Reduzir tráfego de rede? Como chamando a SP (texto pequeno) ao invés de passando uma query (texto maior)? A diferença em geral é negligível. 2) Depende do SGBD mas em geral a única coisa e salvar um pouco de CPU pq a SP já está compilada (tb pode pioerar com o paramet sniffing, etc de novo muitas considerações. 3???? 4) SQL Inject? 5) Para? Pq?

Comment: Um exmeplo é dado pelo própio devMedia **"Quando temos várias aplicações escritas em diferentes linguagens, ou rodam em plataformas diferentes, porém executam a mesma função (no BD)."** Mas acho que seria mais proveitoso vc estudar cada tópico supracitado para esmiuçar cada um para depois vir com dúvidas mais certeiras

Comment: Coisas p/ vc estudar: Parameter Sniffing, SQL Inject attack, Pq remover regras de negócio da camada de banco para a camada de BL

Comment: @jean consideras a pergunta muito ampla? ou pouco elaborada? ou fora do escopo? poderia dar alguma sugestão para que eu possa melhorá-la?

Comment: Eu achei perguntas que não agregam muito. Você deveria aprofundar mais no pq do uso (ou não) de SPs. Dei até dois exemplos rápidos mas tem várias considerações e por menores que ficam muito extensas para uma pergunta só. Seria legal vc estudar e vir com dúvidas mais pontuais (claro que é só uma sugestão)

Comment: @jean agradeço a sugestão, irei segui-la, realmente queria poder ler sobre alguma experiência na prática de alguém da comunidade, imaginei que essa experiência prática, seria bem vista por todos, mas pelos down votes eu me enganei =(

Comment: Não se desanime a comunidade é ótima. É que deu a impressão q vc não pesquisou bem antes de perguntar e tem gente que dá donwvote por isso. Na SO é a mesma coisa

Answer (score 1):

Dois exemplos:

1. Duas aplicações um web service feito em C# e uma aplicação desktop feita em Delphi precisam rodar uma regra de negócio implementada no BD. Para melhor manutenção e gerencialmente é melhor que ambas acessem a mesma SP ao invés de cada uma tentar implementar uma query. Assim qq mudança nessa lógica seria feita alterando a SP ao invés de gerar manutenção em dois sistemas distintos.
   Note que o mesmo resultado poderia ser obtido se ambas as aplicações pudessem chamar uma DLL que encapsula-se essas regras de negócio (a menos que rodem em diferentes SO).
2. Performance. Algumas rotinas ficam realmente muito mais rápidas se implementadas diretamente no BD. Embora eu seja a favor de manter as regras de negócio na camada de regras de negócio tem vezes que é inevitável.
   Nesses caso a rotina pode ser implementada como uma SP, como a SP fica armazenada "compilada" no BD pode haver um ganho de performance se essa rotina é chamada muitas (milhares de) vezes (por dia/hora). Claro isso depende se comparada a ad hoc queries, queries não parametrizadas, etc. Mesmo usando SP pode haver considerações sobre SQL Inject (segurança) e Parameter Sniffing (performance)

Answer (score 1):

Vejamos as possibilidades:

> 1. reduzir o tráfego de rede
> 2. melhorar a performance de banco de dados
> 3. criar tarefas agendadas
> 4. diminuir riscos
> 5. criar rotinas de processamentos

Na minha concepção, a principal motivação seria a número 5. A principal ideia de *Stored Procedures* é a de encapsular comportamento junto com o banco de dados, quando por qualquer motivo, não seja desejável que esses estejam modelados na(s) aplicação(ões) cliente(s). É essa a principal razão (mas não a única) que motiva o uso de *Stored Procedures*.

Os motivos 3 e 4 são algo que derivam do 5. Os motivos 1 e 2, apesar de válidos, são otimizações que só devem ser criadas como casos especiais para resolver problemas pontuais.

Um exemplo real do uso de *Stored Procedure* seria o de criar algum procedimento de CRUD qualquer, principalmente se envolver várias tabelas e colocá-lo diretamente no banco de dados. A vantagem de fazer-se isso é a de que o acesso aos dados é encapsulado e a complexidade do cliente é reduzida. No caso do item 3, você pode até mesmo eliminar a necessidade de haver um programa cliente.

A desvantagem é que mudanças em requisitos e em regras de negócio demandam alterações no banco de dados, que tendem a ser mais custosas e difíceis que alterações nas aplicações nos clientes.

Outra vantagem é que se houver vários programas cliente, com o uso de *Stored Procedures*, você centraliza as regras de negócio todas num lugar só. Entretanto, essa vantagem é considerada superada hoje em dia. Você pode usar um serviço web (SOAP, REST ou outra coisa) que detém o acesso exclusivo ao banco de dados e todas as demais aplicações clientes só o acessariam por meio desse serviço web. Dessa forma, o serviço web seria o responsável por centralizar as regras de negócio, e não mais o banco de dados.

Os casos 1 e 2 também podem ser vantajosos naquelas circunstâncias onde você faz um `SELECT` gigante com várias tabelas e a aplicação cliente usa isso pra agrupar, totalizar ou fazer algum outro processamento. Você consegue reduzir o tráfego de rede entre o servidor de banco de dados e a aplicação cliente, e com isso melhorar a performance, se essas operações forem realizadas diretamente pelo SGBD por meio de *Stored Procedures*.